# Cookie Error while getting OAuth Access Token from GitHub

Tags: java, github, oauth, okhttp

I am trying to get a GitHub oauth access token. Redirecting the user to 
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize works fine and a get the code.

However, when I do the POST request from the server to https://github.com/login/oauth/acces_token, 
the server responds with

> 403: Forbidden / Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.

Am I getting something wrong here? It's an API! What is the role of cookies here? How can I fix the error?

My Code is (using OkHttp)

```
String code= ...;
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
  .scheme("https").host("github.com")
  .addPathSegments("login/oauth/acces_token")
  .build();

StringBuilder formEncoded = new StringBuilder();
formEncoded.append("client_id=").append(URLEncoder.encode(..., "UTF-8"));
formEncoded.append("&client_secret=").append(URLEncoder.encode(..., "UTF-8"));
formEncoded.append("&code=").append(URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8"));

Response resp = client.newCall(
  new Request.Builder().url(url)
  .post(RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
    formEncoded.toString()))
  .addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build())
  .execute();
if (resp.code() != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
    log.error("Error while getting token: {}: {} / {}", 
      resp.code(), resp.message(), resp.body().string());
    throw new RuntimeException("Error while getting access token");
}
```

Comment: see also http://fajitanachos.com/Authenticating-with-the-GitHub-API/ and https://github.com/vjeux/GithubLogin/blob/master/token.php

Answer (score 2):

Found the error: Typo in the URL. I had acces_token, should be access_token. Now it works like a charm.